# Ajax fetch Laravel возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

JS:

```
let url = '/get-place-price';
let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
let content = document.querySelector('.content');
let item = document.querySelector('#start_place');

function onClick(){
    fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json, text-plain, */*",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token,
        },
        method: 'post',
        credentials: "same-origin",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: 'Tushar',
            number: '78987'
        })
    })
        .then((data) => {
            content.innerHTML = data.result;
            console.log(data.result);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

item.onchange = function () {
    onClick();
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/get-place-price', [\App\Http\Controllers\User\CarAjaxController::class, 'place'])->name('order.place');
```

Controller:

```
public function place(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $number = $request->get('number');

    return response()->json(['result'=>'Ajax request submitted successfully']);
}
```

[image: Консоль]

Answer (score -1):

Может для начала прочитать документацию по использованию [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

```
fetch(url, {
    headers    : {
        "Content-Type"    : "application/json",
        "Accept"          : "application/json, text-plain, */*",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN"    : token,
    },
    method     : 'post',
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body       : JSON.stringify({
                                    name  : 'Tushar',
                                    number: '78987'
                                })
})
    .then(response => response.json())// <--
    .then(data => {
        content.innerHTML = data;
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```